# how to join socket room or channel in Socket.IO-client in android

Tags: android, websocket, socket.io

I'm new to socket programming and in a project i'm using [Socket.IO-client Java](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java) to create socket connection between android device and a server . server side developers asked me to connect to the server and then join in a specific room/channel . I'm OK with the first part but how can i join in a room over socket ??

my code is as below :

```js
private void ConnectAndJoin() {
        Log.e("starting:","starting!");

        final Socket socket;
        try {
            socket = IO.socket("http://192.168.1.6:5000");
            socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    socket.emit("foo", "hi");
                    Log.e("status:","connected- sent");

                    socket.
                }

            }).on("event", new Emitter.Listener() {

                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    Log.e("status:","event2");

                }

            }).on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {

                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    Log.e("status:","disconnected");

                }

            });
            socket.connect();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            Log.e("status:","done with error");
        }
```

Please give me a help!

Comment: i think here is the problem                           socket.

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: i don't have much idea but i think you have to remove that line and run it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't join a room with socket io from the client side . it should happens in the server side.

```
socket.emit('join-room' , roomName or RoomId)
```

to tackle this you need to emit a socket  with the room you want to join as data , and in the server you listen to this socket and call socket.join() with the name or the id of the room that has been sent.

```
      socket.on("join-room", new Emitter.Listener() {
      @Override
      public void call(Object... args) {
        room = args[0];
        socket.join(room);
      }
    });
```

warning : I do not know java so for java devs if you see a syntax mistake you can comment i'll update it

hope it helps!

Comment: This answer is working or not ? what's join here? I can't get any suggestion for join

Comment: join is the method for entering a room (listen & send) , it should be called on the server , socket.join will not work on the client side

Comment: it's possible in server side. My problem is i am sending room number from client side(android). How can i send it to server side.

Comment: socket.emit("join-room-event", room_id ) ; and on the server , you listen to this event with socket.on("join-room-event" , callback) ;

Comment: can you please add me in hangouts (tamilairy@gmail.com) or share your email please. i want to discuss little thing about socket client side